# Read relative static file in src

Tags: java

I have .tpl file containing some static content in a package in **src**.
e.g. `src/A/B/C/test.tpl` and i'm trying to read it from a class sibling that file (`src/A/B/C/Test`).

I can't find it in any way! FileReader throws FileNotFoundException.

**SOLUTION:** Class.getResource() works. Problem is about tpl extension which will not be compiled by default. IDEs have setting to add extensions to compile. I used .html instead of updating compiler settings.

```
Test.class.getResource("/A/B/C/test.html").getPath().replace("%20", " ")
```

Comment: What do you need to do with the file? While it's inside the JAR you can get a URL reference to it or open it as an InputStream, but that's it. If you need a path to the file then you have to move it or extract it out of the JAR at runtime.

Comment: This is template file. I read it, replace some placeholders and tags then send it to print and flush...

Comment: If it works you should accept the answer... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110460/how-to-improve-accept-rate-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 3):

You should use [ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

```
getClassloader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the file to src/main/resources and then trying something like -

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/test.tpl");

    try {

        context.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.tpl");

       ...
        } 
   catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Correct. Using "this" does not work in static context. So you can't do this.getClassLoader(). Just an example. I hadn't seen Aviram's answer.